# Use of "Au plaisir" at the end of a correspondance

Tags: politesse, correspondance

It is a form I see frequently on emails in Québec. Is it a reasonable equivalent to "regards" if sending out correspondence in two languages? It seems less stiff than "cordialement". Should it be used in correspondence with people you have not met before?

Answer (score 8):

Les usages sont différents dans les divers pays de la francophonie. « Au plaisir » est, je crois, plus courant au Québec qu'en France. « Au plaisir » se comprend en France mais est peu employé, on y dira plus facilement « Au plaisir de vous lire ».
  Dans mes échanges électroniques professionnels (donc hors proches) j'utilise « cordialement » en français et « *regards* »  en anglais. On utilise « cordialement » aussi avec des personnes qu'on connaît mais avec lesquelles on n'a pas de lien d’amitié.  On peut aussi le faire précéder d'un adverbe pour lui donner un aspect plus convivial et dire, « bien cordialement » ou  « très cordialement ».

---

Usage is different in various parts of the French speaking world. I think  "*Au plaisir*" is more common in Québec than in France. People will understand "*Au plaisir*" in France, but it is not much used and when used usually followed by something, such as "*Au plaisir de vous lire*".
In my work related email correspondence I use "Regards" when writing in English and "*cordialement*" when writing in French. "*Cordialement*" is not really stiff, it can be used with people we have never met but also with people we know but with who we have no personnal realtionship. If you think it is too stiff, you can soften it by using an adverb, and say *"Bien cordialement*"  or "*Très cordialement*".

Comment: J'ajouterai que "Au plaisir" peut s'utiliser en France dans le langage oral (bien qu'assez rarement), mais n'est à ma connaissance absolument jamais utilisé à l'écrit.

Comment: Pour le Québec, un [document](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=4946) là-dessus. Merci.

Comment: Absolument pas comme salutation finale en France!

Answer (score 3):

"Au plaisir!" could be used in place of "Until then!" or "Looking forward to it!"
As in, it will be a pleasure to see, to welcome you, to meet you..

Answer (score 2):

The use of "au plaisir" alone sounds a little weird to me. First of all, it should be avoided if it is a man writing to a woman due to the implicit content of this expression (with pleasure...). Then for a French (not from Québec) I would expect to have something following this expression like "Au plaisir de vous rencontrer" which is more or less equivalent to "Dans l'attente de vous rencontrer".

Without anything after, it does not sound formal at all, I would use it only with friends, however with the entire expression ("Au plaisir de vous rencontrer") it is really formal and even more formal than "Cordialement".

Comment: Québécois here. That implicit connotation is not really made here and "Au plaisir" is not often used orally. It is semi formal. I use it with people I don't have a very close relationship with.